# GitlabCI - define a job dependency on some other conditional job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ee

in my case I want to run job `smoke-test` only when the job `deploy` finished sucessfully. There is a keyword [needs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs), that should do exactly that.

However in docs there is also written:

```
In GitLab 13.9 and older, if needs: refers to a job that might not be added to a pipeline because of only, except, or rules, the pipeline might fail to create.
```

And that is exactly my case (pipeline does not even start, because the `deploy` job does not exist). The `deploy` job is conditional using a very complex `rules` condition:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_KUBERNETES_DEPLOYMENT_ENABLED != "true"
      when: never
    - if: $STAGING_CHART_DIRECTORY == ""
      when: never
    - if: $STAGING_NAMESPACE == ""
      when: never
    - if: $CI_REVIEW_DEPLOYMENT_ENABLED != "true" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: never
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID && $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"
      when: never
    - when: on_success
```

I don't want to define duplicit `rules` condition also for the `smoke-test` job - it would be pain to keep consistency.

How to just simply say "run `smoke-test` job only when `deploy` job finished sucessfully" in this case? What is the best practice here?

- maybe set some environment variable in the deploy job `DEPLOY_JOB_SUCCESS=true` and depend on it in `smoke-test` job
- or use some yaml anchor (however in this case the pipeline definitions are not within one yaml file)
- or something else?

I will be thankful for any kind of a hint :)

// gitlab version: GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.4.2-ee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not exactly what you are looking for, but there is a way of not maintaining the rules twice. Actually 3 ways :)

1. using extends aka inheritance - you define the rules ones and extend from it

```yaml
.rules:
   rules:
     - if: ....

deploy:
   extends:
     - .rules

smoke-test:
   extends:
     - .rules
```

2. references - aka composition - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

```yaml
deploy:
   rules:
     - if: ....

smoke-test:
   rules:
     - !reference ['deploy', rules]
```

3. [yaml anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors)

Those 3 ways allow you to reuse your rules easily, and should help you regarding your issue

Comment: Thank you, the 2nd option "references" is exactly what can solve my issue. It also supports references from included configurations - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the trigger functionality for that to create a child pipeline that executes the `smoke-test` step, see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger) and [there](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#examples)

Basically that downstream pipeline would be triggered by your `deploy` step and executes both steps (`deploy` and `smoke-test`)